# php adding/updation xml content tag having =\" "\

Tags: php, html, xml

addxmlcontent.php
//LOAD XML FILE

```
<?php
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($cat.".xml");
    $users = new SimpleXMLElement($xml->asXML());
    $count = count($users);

    $ids = $xml->xpath("//content/id"); // select all ids
    $cur_id = max(array_map("intval", $ids)) + 1; // change objects to `int`, get `max()`, + 1

    $query = $users->addChild("content");
    $query->addChild("id",$cur_id);
    $query->addChild("title",$title);
    $query->addChild("code",$code);
    $query->addChild("postedby",$adminName);
    $query->addChild("image",$lesimg);
    $query->addChild("video",$lesvid);
    $query->addChild("live",$lestry);

    $users->asXML($cat.".xml");

    $xml = simplexml_load_file($cat.".xml");
    $dom = new DOMDocument('1.0');
    $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
    $dom->formatOutput = true;
    $dom->loadXML($xml->asXML());
    $dom->save($cat.".xml");


 header ("location: home.php");
?>
```

myxml.xml structure

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
<content>
<id>3</id>
<title></title>
<code></code>
<postedby></postedby>
<image></image>
</video></video>
<live></live>
</content>
</root>
```

when adding tag with attribite like

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/5DpGuk_fWGQ?list=PL8XXvQHPisgC7VEA0tSgzXK3uL4bfWaF-" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

the output in xml is

```
<live>
<iframe width=\"560\" height=\"315\" src=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/5DpGuk_fWGQ?list=PL8XXvQHPisgC7VEA0tSgzXK3uL4bfWaF-\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</live>
```

the problem is tag with attribute having =\"\"

NOTE: using freehosting site accord this problem.
NOTE: using localhost it works properly without =\"\"

what do u guy think cause this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be a result of the option `magic_quotes_gpc`. It might be turned on in your freehosting site and turned off in your localhost.

Use [get_magic_quotes_gpc()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-magic-quotes-gpc.php) to see whether the option is turned on. If it is, you can use [stripslashes()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php) to filter your data from escaped characters ( such as `\"`)

Comment: great problem solve thanks, ive turnoff the magic quotes in my site                                   by editing the .htacess php_value magic_quotes_gpc off
php_value magic_quotes_runtime off